# Cell Address and Values of Duplicates in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the following Dataset i am trying to get the Date corresponding to Enterprise Sales Singapore in Row 7. It depends on following condition:

- "Offers given" has some value in latest Enterprise Sales Singapore
- Find last duplicate which has some value in "offers given".
- Get the date of next Duplicate which has no value in "offers given"

My approach has been to find the cell address of last duplicate with some value in "Offers given" (B6) then run Vlookup in the range (B7:B10) to get the "Date" value of B7.
But i have been unable to get the cell address B6 instead i am getting B3.

[image]

[Dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EXSEbBgVOkx-QY3UQvw7SQffqa-bdzVIjNr5MDLjTOU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Show a screen shot or example of what you want.

Comment: My guess is that you don't actually just want the cell address of the last duplicate, but rather that you want to DO something with the last duplicate (e.g., reference it, find its date, etc.). The more specific and detailed you can be about the end goal, the better the chances that those here can help you achieve it. I also recommend sharing a link to a spreadsheet containing a small set of realistic data and a manually typed end result you'd like to see.

Comment: I have elaborated the issue and my approach towards solving it.

Comment: Offers Given Column has some value like 1 or it maybe blank otherwise.

Comment: Could you assign 'variable' to the rows you want to get, and represent the range you want to get with the 'variables'? Also appreciated if you could share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: shared the Sheet link also.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(ADDRESS(MAX(IF(
 COUNTIFS(A1:A, A1:A, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A))=MAX(
 COUNTIFS(A1:A, A1:A, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A))), ROW(A1:A), )), COLUMN(A1), 4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i have elaborated my issue further for better understanding.

Comment: @user3314983  Your original question was: *I am trying to find a way to retrieve the Cell Address of the Last Duplicate value in google sheet.* This answer properly answers your question. You should `accept` and try to strip down your new issue and post a new question if you're still having issues.